# Not able to get SSL certificate validated issued using AWS Certificate Manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to add an SSL certificate to my application that is currently deployed on Elastic Beanstalk. I had created the certificate using AWS Certificate Manager using both the validation methods but none of them worked. I neither got an email nor adding the CNAME to godaddy as well as Route 53 got it validated. I had followed the exact steps specified in the documentation. I am the owner of the domain so I should have gotten an email but I didn't. Any idea what might I might be doing wrong?

Also, is there another way to generate the SSL certificate besides AWS CM for my application?

Comment: Do you get any errors that it can't be validated?

Comment: If you chose DNS validation, please make sure that the DNS record exists and is publicly reachable, i.e. you are not using a DNS record that cannot be reached by AWS. You can check this by disconnecting from all available VPNs on your laptop and doing an nslookup on the command line!

Comment: @Marcin I didn't get any error. The DNS was not validated within 72 hours and the certificate expired.

Comment: @MartinLöper I'll try generating another certificate and check the DNS to make sure it can be reached. Thanks!